# How to test if a Zip file is valid in a windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip

I am using the command line version of 7-zip and I can use this to test if a zip file is valid by using the t command.

But I'm trying to create a batch file which will cycle through a bunch of zip files in a directory and do one thing if the zip is empty, and another thing if the zip has some files archived in it.

Any pointers how you do this using a batch file?

Comment: If I understand the answer below shoul help. But first please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes, noted. Sorry. In fact after I'd posted my question I did think this really isn't the done thing here, so I do apologise. And whilst your answer below is really very kind, and helps enormously in reaching my goal, I'm going to learn very little in getting there. What I think I really need is some documentation or even a tutorial for creating batch files like this so I can learn it for myself. But thanks anyway for the content below.

Answer (score 0):

this may help

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "zipPath=C:\temporal\"
set "zipProg=C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"

call:shortIt "%zipPath%", zipPath
call:shortIt "%zipProg%", zipProg

pushd %zipPath%

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b "%zipPath%" ^| find ".zip"') do (
  set/a numFiles=0, isOk=0, size=0, compressed=0
  for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('%zipProg% t "%zipPath%%%a"') do (
    echo %%i | find /I "ok" >NUL && set/a isOK=1
    echo %%i | find /I "files" >NUL && for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%n in ("%%i") do set/a numFiles=%%n
    echo %%i | find /I "size" >NUL && for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%n in ("%%i") do set/a size=%%n
    echo %%i | find /I "compressed" >NUL && for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%n in ("%%i") do set/a compressed=%%n
  )
  if !isOk! neq 0 if !numFiles! equ 0 if !size! neq 0 set/a numFiles=1 

  if !isOk! equ 0 (
       echo(
       echo(%zipPath%%%a is not an archive or an error ocurred
       echo(
  ) else (
    if !numFiles! neq 0 (
      echo(%zipPath%%%a contains !numFiles! files [!size! to !compressed!]
    ) else (
       echo(%zipPath%%%a is empty
    )
  )
)


popd
endlocal

exit/B 0

:shortIt
SetLocal & set "token=%~s1"
EndLocal & set "%2=%token%"
```